# sql pivot with multiple grouping

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I have a table like this:

```
EmpId--Meal--Day--Value

1--Brkfst--1--10

1--Brkfst--1--20

1--Brkfst--2--30

1--Lunch--3--40

2--Brkfst--1--50

2--Lunch--2--60

2--Brkfst--1--70

2--Brkfst--2--80
```

Output should be:

```
EMPID--Meal--Day1--Day2--Day3

1--brkfst--10--30--null

1--brkfst--20--null-null

1--lunch--null--null--40

2--brkfst--50--80--null

2--brkfst--70--null--null
```

Basically each employee can have different values for a meal type but can have multiple meal types in a single day.
imp point is all meal types for a employee should be bunched together in the o/p and all the meal types having a value should be shifted upwards.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't make sense why you have two records for combination of EmpID = 1 and Meal = brkfst. When you Pivot, you must pick something to group by - from your example results i am assuming that you wish to group by EmpId and Meal even though you aren't.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @someTable TABLE (empid INT, Meal VARCHAR(10), [Day] INT, Value INT);

INSERT INTO @someTable(empid, Meal, [Day], Value)
SELECT 1, 'Brkfst', 1, 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Brkfst', 1, 20 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Brkfst', 2, 30 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Lunch',  3, 40 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Brkfst', 1, 50 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Lunch',  2, 60 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Brkfst', 1, 70 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Brkfst', 2, 80;

WITH SRC AS (
    SELECT empid, Meal, [Day], Value
    FROM @someTable        
)
SELECT empid, Meal, [1] AS Day1, [2] AS Day2, [3] AS Day3
FROM SRC
PIVOT(Sum(Value) FOR [Day] IN([1], [2], [3])) P
```

Results:

```
empid       Meal       Day1        Day2        Day3
----------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           Brkfst     30          30          NULL
2           Brkfst     120         80          NULL
1           Lunch      NULL        NULL        40
2           Lunch      NULL        60          NULL
```

Comment: Thanks J Cooper for your reply.
But I dont want to sum up the values.I would want to display all the values for the meals as it is.So if employee 1 has 2 values for breakfast for day 1 and 2 values for breakfast for day 2, then there should be 2 rows for employee 1 with brkfast.if he has 3 values for day 1 and 2 values for day 2 in brkfsast then there should be 3 rows in the o/p with the 3rd value for day 2 as null.I want the o/p just like in my original query. Is there any other solution if its not possible by using pivot and partitions? Thanks!

Comment: @user1202939 - ok, so let's say you have two values (A, B) for employee 1 on day 1 for breakfast. You have also have one value (C) for employee 1 on day2 for breakfast. How do you determine which record value (C) will go with, A or B?

Comment: It should go straight to the top most empty slot.Doesnt matter if its A or B.Only the employee and meal combination should match.

Comment: @user1202939 - this seems like a very awkward requirement. Basically your query results will be Non-Deterministic?? I suspect there is a better way to achieve what you are trying to do. Perhaps explain what it is you're doing and why it is that you want your query results the way that you do?

Comment: Sorry for the very very late reply..I was trying to display the same in a crystal report..but the days are from 1 to 31..The functionality can be achieved by temp tables but when there are like 150000 rows it goes for a toss..Is there any other way it can be achieved without pivot then? Thanks again!